# Intentando utilizar firebase : "cannot resolve FirebaseMessagingService"

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase

Estoy intentando usar `firebase` para notificaciones en segundo plano.

pero no detecta `FirebaseMessagingService` intento `extends` de esta y me dice:

> cannot resolve

en el gradle tengo

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.1.0'
}

compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:16.0.4'
compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:9.8.0'

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

pero si hago un import me sale `com.google.firebase.messaging.` y después de este R o *, No me salen las demás opciones por ejemplo `FirebaseMessagingService` o `FirebaseInstanceIdService` dentro de (iid) aunque este ya he visto que en la documentación que no puede utilizarse.

Quiero obtener y actualizar el token.

Comment: Que compileSdkVersion tienes definida en tu build.grade?

Answer (score 4):

Asegura que las dependencias se encuentren dentro del bloque `dependencies` y que `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'` se encuentre definido en la raíz de tu archivo `build.gradle`:

```
dependencies {
    ...
    ...

    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:xx.x.x'
    compile 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:xx.x.x'
    ...
    ...
}

apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

---

Me parece que tu proyecto no esta actualizado, si lo actualizas y usas una versión gradle 3.0 o mayor tendrías que cambiar compile por `implementation`:

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-core:xx.x.x'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:xx.x.x'
```

ya que el uso `compile` es obsoleto, [te sugiero usar al menos la versión](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client?hl=es-419)

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.1.0'
```

Revisa la documentación:

[Configura una app cliente de Firebase Cloud Messaging en Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client?hl=es-419)

Answer (score 0):

He actualizado la versión de gradle, tal como indicabas en tu respuesta. utilizando ahora implementation. Pero esto no fue la solución. El problema fue la versión de la librería que estaba compilando.

he actualizado a  `implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:17.3.4'` y ya puedo hacer `extends FirebaseMessagingService`

gracias por tu respuesta Jorgesys

saludos.

Comment: Si, de hecho la mínima versión a usar sería la que indico en mi respuesta 17.1.0 ,  revisa la documentación.